# How to navigate to a screen on back button press in React navigation 5 stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

There are many similar questions that have been answered but none of them uses the newest react-navigation version.
I want to go to the 'Home' screen from the 'Document' screen on back button press. This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{ headerShown : false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Camera" component={CameraScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Document" component={Document} options={{
      headerLeft: (props) => (<HeaderBackButton {...props} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Home")}/>)
    }} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Edit for more clarification: My app starts with 'Home' then goes to 'Camera' then to 'Document'. Now, I don't want to go back to 'Camera' once I am at 'Document' rather straight to 'Home' when I press the phone's back button.
According to the documentation, this is how to override the back button.

```
<Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
  headerLeft: (props) => (
   <HeaderBackButton
     {...props}
     onPress={() => {
       // Do something
     }}
   />
 ),
```

}}/>;
But I don't know how to go to 'Home' using the above code. So I searched similar questions and most of them had `navigationOptions` and other stuff. I tried following the below answer from a question.

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation';
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return{
    headerLeft:(<HeaderBackButton onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('A')}}/>)
}
```

}
So yeah, the back button doesn't respond even if I use console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I needed. I had to override the physical back button in 'Document'.

```js
 useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
          const onBackPress = () => {
            navigation.pop(2); // remove two screens i.e. Document and Camera
            return true // disable normal behaviour
          };
          BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress); // detect back button press
          return () =>
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
        }, [])
      );
```

Answer (score 8):

You can customise back button behaviour using navigation 'beforeRemove' event, which fires before unloading a screen.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', e => {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action
      unsubscribe() // Unsubscribe the event on first call to prevent infinite loop
      navigation.navigate('Home') // Navigate to your desired screen
    });
 }, [])
```

The positive point with this approach is that it will fire on any type of back navigation, whether it's in-app back button or device back button/gesture.

[Navigation Events Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `CommonActions.reset` ?

something like this from the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset) :

```js
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

// when you want to navigate to the Documents page, instead of doing
navigation.navigate({routeName: 'Documents'});

// you can try
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Documents',
        params: { name: 'abc' },
      },
    ],
  })
);
```

So that when you're going back from `Documents` you're heading to the previous screen in the stack : `Home`.

Comment: I don't understand how to incorporate this with my functional component

Comment: Dark matter is using ReactNavigation V5.

Comment: @GChevass I am also passing params.  `navigation.navigate('Document', { name : 'abc' })`

Comment: I've added a parameter in my answer

Comment: `The action 'RESET' with payload {"index":1,"routes":[{"name":"Home"},{"name":"Documents","params":{"name":"New Doc 2020-7-13 19-48-58"}}]} was not handled by any navigator.` Getting this error as soon as I go to Document screen

Comment: where did you include this code ? can you share your file ?

Comment: Basically I have a function that creates a folder and takes you to the 'Document'. https://pastebin.com/HxsVvA1f

Comment: and in what component this code is executed ? It must be inside the `Stack Navigator` as the error suggests

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your code works.

<it doesn't work.> - you can give us more information.

But it's worth to try below.

```
import {CommonActions} from '@react-navigation/native';

props.navigation.dispatch(
   CommonActions.navigate({name: 'Home'}),
);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dispatch

Comment: if you want to go to the `Home` screen on a button press for instance `onPress={() => { props.navigation.dispatch ...}}`